# qtp the location you clicked is associated with several objects

Tags: element, qtp

I am trying to get my hands on to QTP 11.5. I have windows 7 with ie8. the issue is whenever I try to add object(webedit) to the Repository I get WinObject:Internet Explorer_Service added with error on top  that "the location you clicked is associated with several objects"

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to add the `WebEdit`? If you're using the object repositories learn capability does the `WebEdit` show up in the selection list or do you get `WinObject` from the get go?

If the later it seems that the Web addin isn't kicking in, make sure you selected **Web** in the addin manager when opening UFT (QTP 11.5 is called UFT now), also open a GUI test before and only then launch the browser, if you open the browser before a GUI test is open UFT may not identify Web controls (this is similar to opening a browser before QTP).

Answer (score 0):

I have never used QTP 11.5 but i guess the problem you are facing is because there may be multiple webedit objects

solution to this can be ----> object spy the webedit object and use more characteristics in your descriptive programming , can explain you better if you give me the part of code and explain its working.

for eg:
strBrowserMainPage.WebButton("class:=sr_but_m","name:=export").exist

Here, i have used two characteristics of webbutton because there where more then one webbutton objects with name = Export

So to select a particular increase the characteristics so as to be more specific on which object.

Thanks

Comment: did the above solution help?